# How to deserialize a list to a map using fastmap

Tags: java, json, fastjson

I have a JSON that has a list of objects inside another object, something like:

```
{
   "name":"name",
   "processes":[
      {
         "id":123,
         "desc":"main"
      },
      {
         "id":456,
         "desc":"secondary"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to parse `fastjson` to something like:

```
public class Idea {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Process>> processes;
    
    //Getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Process {

    private String id;
    private String desc;
    
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Basically, the idea is to map that list from the JSON to a map where the key is something like `Processes` and the values are the list got from the JSON.

Any idea on how I could do it?

Comment: `processes` is a `List<Processes>`, not a map

Comment: I know, but I need to add that list to a map, because in the future is likely we have more list in the Json and they'll be added to that map with a different key

Comment: OK, it was just to clarify that